# Update only the checked rows using sigmagrid

Tags: jquery, sigma-grid-control

How to make sigma grid update only the checked rows??

so that when the users click the save button, only checked rows will be updated.

maybe anyone ever use this method?? o.O

in the cols option i've added this line to show checkbox, but when i click the save button,

it seems the checked rows doesn't have any effect at all :(

```
 {id: 'chk' ,isCheckColumn : true, frozen: true, editable:false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with setting

```
selectRowByCheck : true,
```

in var gridOption={

it should enable the checked rows to be those that are applied. But the row still needs to have had something modified...